# Span a function across several consecutive elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Suppose that I have a list called `list`.  I would like to span an arbitrary function `f` across specified consecutive elements in `list`.

Here is an example.  Suppose the following:

```
list = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};
```

I would like to obtain the following new lists:

```
{f[{10, 20, 30, 40}], 50, 60, 70}
{10, f[{20, 30, 40, 50}], 60, 70}
{10, 20, 30, 40, f[{50, 60, 70}]}
```

Is there a simple (perhaps even built-in) way to accomplish this in Mathematica 8?  I have come up with the following function `spanMap`, but my method seems very complicated and clunky:

```
spanMap[function_, list_List, begin_Integer, end_Integer] := 
 Module[{result},
  If[begin == 1,
   If[end == Length[list], result = list;];
   If[begin < end < Length[list], 
    result = 
      Flatten[{function[list[[begin ;; end]]], 
        list[[(end + 1) ;;]]}];];
   ];

  If[begin > 1,
   If[end == Length[list], 
    result = 
      Flatten[{list[[1 ;; (begin - 1)]], 
        function[list[[begin ;; end]]]}];];
   If[begin < end < Length[list], 
    result = 
      Flatten[{list[[1 ;; (begin - 1)]], 
        function[list[[begin ;; end]]], list[[(end + 1) ;;]]}];];
   ];

  result
  ]
```

where

```
spanMap[f, list, 1, 4]
spanMap[f, list, 2, 5]
spanMap[f, list, 5, 7]
```

yield the desired results:

```
{f[{10, 20, 30, 40}], 50, 60, 70}
{10, f[{20, 30, 40, 50}], 60, 70}
{10, 20, 30, 40, f[{50, 60, 70}]}
```

albeit in a complicated, clunky way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a good example where `` Internal`PartitionRagged `` (IPR) can be used very effectively. First, observe the following:

```
list = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};

(* 3 continuous elements in the middle *)
Internal`PartitionRagged[list, {2, 3, 2}]
(* {{10, 20}, {30, 40, 50}, {60, 70}} *)

(* 3 continuous elements from the start *)
Internal`PartitionRagged[list, {0, 3, 4}]
(* {{}, {10, 20, 30}, {40, 50, 60, 70}} *)

(* 3 continuous elements at the end *)
Internal`PartitionRagged[list, {4, 3, 0}]
(* {{10, 20, 30, 40}, {50, 60, 70}, {}} *)
```

You see that for a "continuous span", you can always partition the list into 3 parts as `{initial, continuous span, final}` by properly choosing the arguments to IPR. This means that you simply need to `MapAt` your function `f` onto the second element of the partitioned list and then flatten it.

The function you want can be written as:

```
spanMap[f_, list_, {start_, end_}] := MapAt[
    f, Internal`PartitionRagged[list, {start - 1, end - start + 1, Length@list - end}], {2}
] ~Flatten~ 1
```

which is pretty clean and intuitive, IMO. Try it out!

```
spanMap[f, list, {1, 4}]
spanMap[f, list, {2, 5}]
spanMap[f, list, {5, 7}]

(*  {f[{10, 20, 30, 40}], 50, 60, 70}
    {10, f[{20, 30, 40, 50}], 60, 70}
    {10, 20, 30, 40, f[{50, 60, 70}]} *)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works great!  Just out of curiosity, where is `Internal\`PartitionRagged` documented?  Is this a separate package?  I can't seem to find `PartitionRagged`, `Internal`, or `Internal\`PartitionRagged` in the Mathematica 8 Documentation Center.

Comment: @Andrew ``Internal` `` functions are not documented on purpose, but are used extensively in the _Mathematica_ source code and are generally stable enough to be used in one's code and you can expect it to be around in future versions (don't quote me on this though). You learn about the usage of such functions from trial and error or from posts here and on MathGroup

Answer (score 8):

### Generic element-grouping function

Several years ago, I wrote a simplistic [HTML parser](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/jMICGBQ1EEw), for which I wrote a generalization of the function you request, that works on different levels of expression, and groups elements at specified start and end positions in specified heads.

### Implementation

Here is the code (I made no effort to improve it, so it may not be optimal or the most elegant):

```
ClearAll[        
    listSplit,
    reconstructIntervals,
    groupElements,
    groupPositions,
    processPosList,
    groupElementsNested
];    


(* My analog of Internal`PartitionRagged*)
listSplit[x_List,lengthlist_List,headlist_List]:=
    MapThread[            
        #1@@Take[x,#2]&,
        {                
            headlist,
            Transpose[({Most[#1]+1,Rest[#1]}&)[FoldList[Plus,0,lengthlist]]]
        }
    ];

(* Reconstruct split intervals from positions *)
reconstructIntervals[listlen_Integer,ints_List]:=
    Module[{missed,startint,lastint},            
        startint=If[ints[[1,1]]==1,{},{1,ints[[1,1]]-1}];
        lastint=If[ints[[-1,-1]]==listlen,{},{ints[[-1,-1]]+1,listlen}];
        missed=
            (If[#1[[2,1]]-#1[[1,2]]>1,{#1[[1,2]]+1,#1[[2,1]]-1},{}]&)/@
                Partition[ints,2,1];
        missed=Join[missed,{lastint}];
        Prepend[Flatten[Transpose[{ints,missed}],1],startint]
    ];

(* Groups elements and wraps them in specified heads *)    
groupElements[lst_List,poslist_List,headlist_List]/;
OrderedQ[Flatten[Sort[poslist]]]&&Length[headlist]==Length[poslist]:=
   Module[{totalheadlist,allints,llist},          
      totalheadlist=
         Append[                
            Flatten[
               Transpose[{Array[Sequence&,{Length[headlist]}],headlist}],1
            ],
            Sequence
         ];
      allints=reconstructIntervals[Length[lst],poslist];
      llist=(If[#1==={},0,1-Subtract@@#1]&)/@allints;
      listSplit[lst,llist,totalheadlist]
   ];

(* To work on general heads, we need this *)
groupElements[h_[x__],poslist_List,headlist_List]:=
   h[Sequence@@groupElements[{x},poslist,headlist]];

(* If we have a single head *)
groupElements[expr_,poslist_List,head_]:=
   groupElements[expr,poslist,Table[head,{Length[poslist]}]];

(* Group positions, to create a specification for nested grouping functon*)
groupPositions[plist_List]:=
   Reap[(Sow[Last[#1],{Most[#1]}]&)/@plist,_,List][[2]];

(* Finds pairs of positions for opening and closing elements, to form intervals *)
processPosList::nomtchMessageName="Unmatched lists for positions `1`";
processPosList[{openlist_List,closelist_List}]:=
   Module[{opengroup,closegroup,poslist},          
      {opengroup,closegroup}=groupPositions/@{openlist,closelist};
      poslist=Transpose[(Transpose[Sort[#1]]&)/@{opengroup,closegroup}];
      If[             
         UnsameQ@@poslist[[1]]
         ,             
         Message[processPosList::nomtchMessageName,{openlist,closelist}];
         Return[{}]
         ,
         (*else*)
         poslist=Transpose[{poslist[[1,1]],Transpose/@Transpose[poslist[[2]]]}]
      ]
   ];


(* Main function to group elements in an expression *)        
groupElementsNested[nested_,{openposlist_List,closeposlist_List},head_]/;
Head[head]=!=List:=
   Fold[          
      Function[{x,y},MapAt[groupElements[#1,y[[2]],head]&,x,{y[[1]]}]],
      nested,
      Sort[             
         processPosList[{openposlist,closeposlist}],
         Length[#2[[1]]]<Length[#1[[1]]]&
      ]
   ];
```

This code was instrumental for the kind of HTML parser I wanted - it was a breadth-first parser that could also (partially) parse certain types of malformed HTML documents. Speed of parsing was important, and the above functions were reasonably fast for my purposes.

### Examples

#### Combining integers in a nested list based on a list of positions

Create a test expression (nested list here, but in general this can be a general expression)

```
testlist = 
  Partition[Partition[Sort[Table[Random[Integer, {1, 200}], {64}]], 8], {2, 8}]

(*
    {{{{6, 8, 12, 13, 17, 17, 22, 23}, {26, 34, 35, 39, 39, 41,44, 49}}}, 
     {{{51, 52, 53, 54, 61, 64, 65, 67}, {67, 69, 73, 78,82, 87, 91, 93}}}, 
     {{{95,98,100,113,124,129,132,132}, {135,140,142,149,150,153,155, 157}}}, 
     {{{160,162,163,165,167,167,170,181}, {183,185,185,191,193,194,196,197}}}}
*)
```

Here is a sample list of positions. Its first element is a list of opening positions for the element intervals, and the second list is a list of closing positions.

```
positions = {
   {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 6}, {2, 1, 2, 3}, {3,1, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 2, 1}}, 
   {{1, 1, 1, 4}, {1, 1, 1, 8}, {2, 1, 2, 5}, {3, 1, 1, 7}, {3, 1, 2, 5}}
};
```

We now group elements according to the position specification above, and wrap them in the head `hd`:

```
groupElementsNested[testlist, positions , hd]

(* 
   {{{{hd[6, 8, 12, 13], 17, hd[17, 22, 23]}, {26, 34, 35, 39,39, 41, 44, 49}}},
   {{{51, 52, 53, 54, 61, 64, 65, 67}, {67, 69, hd[73, 78, 82], 87, 91, 93}}},
   {{{95, hd[98, 100, 113, 124, 129, 132], 132}, {hd[135, 140, 142, 149, 150], 153, 155, 157}}}, 
   {{{160, 162, 163, 165, 167, 167, 170, 181}, {183, 185, 185, 191, 193, 194, 196, 197}}}}
*)
```

#### Combining consecutive elements matching the same pattern

One can also do more interesting things. Here are some additional functions that would allow us to group elements which all match certain pattern:

```
ClearAll[getOpenClosePositions];
getOpenClosePositions[expr_,patt_]:=
   (If[#1==={},{},Transpose[#1]]&)[          
      Reap[             
         (Sow[#1,{Most[#1]}]&)/@Position[expr,patt],
         _,
         ({First[#1],Last[#1]}&)[#2]&
      ][[2]]
   ];


ClearAll[groupMatched];
groupMatched[expr_,patt_,head_]:=
   groupElementsNested[expr,getOpenClosePositions[expr,patt],head];
```

Now we can, for example, group according to some pattern, such as

```
groupMatched[       
   testlist,
   x_Integer/;IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{1,15},{30,40},{100,130}],x],
   hd
]

(*
{       
   {{{hd[6,8,12,13],17,17,22,23},{26,hd[34,35,39,39],41,44,49}}},
   {{{51,52,53,54,61,64,65,67},{67,69,73,78,82,87,91,93}}},
   {{{95,98,hd[100,113,124,129],132,132},{135,140,142,149,150,153,155,157}}},
   {{{160,162,163,165,167,167,170,181},{183,185,185,191,193,194,196,197}}}
}
*)
```

#### Simple Mathematica `FullForm` parser

Here will be a less trivial example: parse a string of Mathematica code, given that it represents the `FullForm` (which makes the task of parsing vastly simpler). Here is one possible implementation for such a parser:

```
ClearAll[parse,parsedToCode,tokenize,Bracket];

(* "tokenize" our string *)
tokenize[code_String]:=
   Module[{n=0,tokenrules},          
      tokenrules=
         {                
            "[":>{"Open",++n},
            "]":>{"Close",n--},
            Whitespace|""~~","~~Whitespace|""
         };
      DeleteCases[StringSplit[code,tokenrules],"",\[Infinity]]
   ];

(* 
 ** parses the "tokenized" string in the breadth-first manner starting 
 ** with the outermost brackets, using Fold and  groupElementsNested
*)
parse[preparsed_]:=
   Module[
   {          
      maxdepth=Max[Cases[preparsed,_Integer,\[Infinity]]],
      popenlist,
      parsed,
      bracketPositions
   },          
      bracketPositions[expr_,brdepth_Integer]:=
         {Position[expr,{"Open",brdepth}],Position[expr,{"Close",brdepth}]};
      parsed=
         Fold[                
            groupElementsNested[#1,bracketPositions[#1,#2],Bracket]&,
            preparsed,
            Range[maxdepth]
         ];
      parsed=DeleteCases[parsed,{"Open"|"Close",_},\[Infinity]];
      parsed=parsed//. 
         h_[x___,y_,Bracket[z___],t___]:>h[x,y[z],t]
   ];

(* convert our parsed expression into a code that Mathematica can execute *)
parsedToCode[parsed_]:=
   ReleaseHold[
      (#1//. 
         x_String:>ToExpression[x,InputForm,HoldForm]&)//@parsed/. 
         HoldPattern[Sequence[x__][y__]]:>x[y]
   ];
```

This is a breadth-first parser. Basically, it starts from a list of string tokens and iteratively grows the resulting expression from it, in a breadth-first manner.

Here is an example to show how it works. First construct a string to parse:

```
stringToParse=ToString[DownValues[groupPositions]]
```

> ```
>  "List[RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[groupPositions[Pattern[plist, Blank[List]]]], Part[Reap[Map[Function[Sow[Last[Slot[1]], List[Most[Slot[1]]]]], plist], Blank[], List], 2]]]"
> ```

Now tokenize the string. The process of tokenizing also identifies square brackets and adds their depth.

```
initlist=tokenize[stringToParse]

(* 
   {"List", {"Open", 1}, "RuleDelayed", {"Open",2}, "HoldPattern", {"Open", 3},
    "groupPositions", {"Open", 4}, "Pattern", {"Open", 5}, "plist", "Blank",
    {"Open", 6}, "List", {"Close", 6}, {"Close", 5}, {"Close", 4}, {"Close", 3},
    "Part", {"Open", 3}, "Reap", {"Open", 4}, "Map", {"Open", 5}, "Function", 
    {"Open", 6}, "Sow", {"Open", 7}, "Last", {"Open", 8}, "Slot", {"Open", 9}, 
    "1", {"Close", 9}, {"Close", 8}, "List", {"Open", 8}, "Most", {"Open", 9}, 
    "Slot", {"Open", 10}, "1", {"Close", 10}, {"Close", 9}, {"Close", 8}, 
    {"Close", 7}, {"Close", 6}, "plist", {"Close", 5}, "Blank", {"Open", 5},
    {"Close", 5}, "List", {"Close", 4}, "2", {"Close", 3}, {"Close", 2}, 
    {"Close", 1}}
*)
```

We can now parse this. The idea is to combine together all elements in between the closest pair of opening and closing square brackets of the same depth. This is done in the line with `Fold`, in the `parse` function.

```
parse[tokenize[stringToParse]]
```

> ```
> {
>    "List"[
>       "RuleDelayed"[             
>          "HoldPattern"["groupPositions"["Pattern"["plist","Blank"["List"]]]],
>          "Part"[                
>             "Reap"[                   
>                "Map"[                      
>                   "Function"["Sow"["Last"["Slot"["1"]],"List"["Most"["Slot"["1"]]]]],
>                   "plist"
>                ],
>                "Blank"[],
>                "List"
>             ],
>             "2"
>          ]
>       ]
>    ]
> }
> ```

At each pass (single iteration in `Fold`), we process all brackets at the same depth in an expression. The important thing here is that after the first pass, the resulting expression becomes nested, and is no longer a simple list of tokens. Therefore, here we do need the full power of `groupElementsNested` function to repeatedly combine elements deeper and deeper inside expression being built.

Finally, we can use the `parsedToCode` function to convert the above result (where all heads are still strings) into Mathematica code:

```
parsedToCode[parse[tokenize[stringToParse]]]
```

> ```
> {
>    {
>       HoldPattern[groupPositions[plist_List]]:>
>          Reap[(Sow[Last[#1],{Most[#1]}]&)/@plist,_,List][[2]]
>    }
> }
> ```

which is what we started with.

The HTML parser mentioned before is based on the same set of ideas, but it has more types of "brackets" - instead of just square brackets, all HTML tags play a role of brackets of different types.

Answer (score 6):

```
spanMap[f_, list_, s_, k_] := Join[list[[;; s - 1]], 
                                   {f@list[[s ;; k]]}, 
                                   list[[-Length@list + k ;;]]]

list = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};
spanMap[f, list, 1, 4]
spanMap[f, list, 1, 7]
```

> ```
> {f[{10, 20, 30, 40}], 50, 60, 70}
> {f[{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70}]}
> ```

If You want safer version add condition at the end:

```
spanMap[f_, list_, s_, k_] := Join[list[[;; s - 1]], 
                                   {f@list[[s ;; k]]}, 
                                   list[[-Length@list + k ;;]]
                                  ]/; (0 < s < k \[And] 0 < k <= Length@list)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this way:

```
spanMap[f_, list_, {start_, end_}] := Replace[
  MapAt[f, list, 
     List /@ Range[start, end]] /. {x___Integer, 
      seq : (PatternSequence[f[_] ..]), y___Integer} :> {x, {seq}, 
      y} /. f[n_] :> n, lst_List :> f@lst, 2]
```

**UPDATE**: As there are three solutions I did some benchmarking to see which one is faster. I used the following code:

```
Do[
  spanMap[f, Range[1, 100, 1], {RandomInteger[{1, 49}], RandomInteger[{50, 100}]}], 
{10000}] // Timing
```

The results obtained were 25.013066s for my answer (by far the slowest), then 0.525158s for rm -rf and .153444s for Kuba's answer (the fastest).

Comment: Ooops! Thank you @Kuba for pointing this out. I have now corrected the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
<< Presentations`

list = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};

list // MapLevelParts[f, {{2, 3, 4, 5}}]

{10, f[{20, 30, 40, 50}], 60, 70}
```

Also:

```
list // MapLevelParts[f, {{1, 3, 5}}]

{f[{10, 30, 50}], 20, 40, 60, 70}
```

Comment: David -- I don't seem to be able to load `<<Presentations` in order to get at the `MapLevelParts` function. Also, I see from the link below that you have done this before? Is there a story here? http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2003/Nov/msg00342.html

Comment: WRI never put it in Mathematica, and probably never will. It's in the Presentations Application, which I sell.

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way (I certainly don't object; in fact you can read my argument [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/)), but it doesn't sit well with some users if many references are made to commercial packages such as yours. I think it would go a long way to addressing such objections, while still not undermining your product (since there is a lot more to `Presentations\`` than this), if you would perhaps post the definition of this simple function so that your code can be compared more fairly with the other answers.

Comment: It was the simplest answer to the question posted. My answer was a direct answer to the poster's subsequent question. It is extremely inexpensive compared to its size and capabilities. If you are employed at all I'll wager that you make 1 or 2 orders of magnitude more than I from your technical work. One of the reasons I don't appear much on this group is that if I ever mention Presentations I get a lot of flack. So I do take offense.

Comment: I actually bought a copy of Presentations and can agree that it is a good package and excellent value for money--thank you for your hard work. I know that people react negatively to it and I do not agree with this at all, so I was trying to make a suggestion that could improve how your answers are received in future given prevailing attitudes. Moreover, I only suggested that because you already posted the definition of `MapLevelParts` on MathGroup anyway. I am on your side on this issue and certainly did not mean for my comment to come across as pedantic or demanding. If so, I apologize.