# Need a function that, given f, a function of two arguments, calls f on successive elements of the list and the result of the last evaluation of f

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Suppose I have a list

```
{a[1], a[2], a[3], ...}
```

and a function

```
y = f[x1, x2]
```

Is it possible to return a list like

```
{a[1], f[a[2],a[1]], f[a[3], f[a[2],a[1]]], ... ]
```

This may look like a little bit confusing. Actually, it just applies the function across consecutive elements in this list in order.

1st time, take a[1] and a[2] and act on a[2]:

```
{a[1], f[a[2], a[1]], a[3], ...}
```

2nd time, take a[3] and **the new** a[2] and act on a[3]:

```
{a[1], f[a[2], a[1]], f[a[3], f[a[2], a[1]]], ...}
```

In other words, although the problem is very similar to [Span a function across several consecutive elements in a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28521/span-a-function-across-several-consecutive-elements-in-a-list), the order / history of the application matters.

Is there a way that it can be realized elegantly without using For loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList):

```
FoldList[f[#2, #1]&, Array[a, 5]]
```

> {a[1], f[a[2], a[1]], f[a[3], f[a[2], a[1]]], f[a[4], f[a[3], f[a[2], a[1]]]],
>     f[a[5], f[a[4], f[a[3], f[a[2], a[1]]]]]}

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer. I couldn't believe there exists exactly a function designed for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map[
Reverse@Array[a, #] //. {a[x_], p : Repeated[a[_], {2, Infinity}]} :> 
{a[x], {p}} /. List :> f &, Range[5]]

(* {a[1], f[a[2], a[1]], f[a[3], f[a[2], a[1]]], f[a[4], f[a[3], f[a[2], a[1]]]],
f[a[5], f[a[4], f[a[3], f[a[2], a[1]]]]]} *)
```